# Wine over ssh X11 forward, keyboard problem

Tags: x11, keyboard, remote, wine

When i run:

```
ssh -X myRemoteLinuxIP gvim
```

everything works fine.

But when i run:

```
ssh -X myRemoteLinuxIP wine notepad
```

mouse works OK, but keyboard keep typing chars inside ssh terminal window, not inside notepad. What am i doing wrong?

- keyboard-locales are same on both computers (us layout).
- using DWM as window manager, but also tried OpenBox and Xwfm4, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is some bug related to wine in combination with some or all window managers... But I finally found one working solution for my needs:

```
startx <(echo ssh -X myRemoteLinuxIP wine notepad)
```

which runs wine application as single-app without window manager. And keyboard is finally routed inside the program.